# T-SQL MERGE with UPDATE SET CASE Statement - What happens without ELSE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm writing a TSQL MERGE statement to handle the usual combination of UPDATE and INSERT.  I have a couple of select columns which should only be updated if (for example) a parameter is set to TRUE.  For example:

```
...
UPDATE SET
    TARGET.[SomeColumn] =
        CASE
        WHEN @someParameter = 1 THEN SOURCE.[SomeColumn]
    END,
...
```

According to all documentation I could find, ELSE is definitely optional (as with most languages) but I don't understand what will happen if omitted here.

I could of course do the following:

```
...
UPDATE SET
    TARGET.[SomeColumn] =
        CASE
        WHEN @someParameter = 1 THEN SOURCE.[SomeColumn]
        ELSE TARGET.[SomeColumn] --This is the new line
    END,
...
```

.. but that seems to carry what feels like unnecessary overhead in re-writing existing values.

So my question is what would happen if `ELSE` was omitted and `@someParameter` is set to 0 (FALSE), does this fail, set NULL, leave the value unchanged, or...?

Comment: If you omit `else`, then the `case` statement returns `NULL`.  Hence, the value is set to `NULL`.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff says you'll get `NULL` for anything that doesn't match your WHEN statement, ELSE provides a catch all to tell it what to do for everything that doesn't match one of the WHEN statements (you can have more than one, remember).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Makes perfect sense when you put it like that.  Thank you so much for your prompt response.

Comment: @Bridge Thanks for confirming.  The answer is so simple, I'm starting to feel a little silly for asking it!

Answer (score 3):

The facts that it's in an `UPDATE` in a `MERGE` are actually irrelevant, although you weren't to know that. The relevant [documentation is that for the `CASE` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> `ELSE` *else_result_expression*
>
> Is the expression returned if no
>   comparison operation evaluates to `TRUE`. If this argument is omitted
>   and no comparison operation evaluates to `TRUE`, `CASE` returns
>   `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the part.  I read through that same page - and yet somehow managed to completely miss that part!!!

Answer (score 3):

No ELSE in a CASE means NULL as per MSDN

However, MERGE offers another way doing it which will work for multiple columns

```
WHEN MATCHED AND @someParameter = 1 THEN
    UPDATE SET
        TARGET.[SomeColumn] = SOURCE.[SomeColumn],
        TARGET.[SomeColumn2] = SOURCE.[SomeColumn2]
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion and in this simplicity of my example works perfectly.  I wanted to do it that way initially, but there's actually a few parameters this needs doing for in my case, and of course a single MERGE statement cannot update the same record more than once.  Sometimes I wonder if it would be better to split out INSERT and UPDATE in my case to simplify both, however I always try to look for methods that perform the all tasks in one go (where possible).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here's an example I put together for an ETL job I've implemented. It does seem to need the else statements to work properly. This is in SQL Server 2017 with Temporal Tables.

```
-- match to target on id
merge into Flags with (tablock) as target
using #Flags as source
  on source.id = target.id
-- on match update row
when matched then
  update set
    -- flags 1-4 can't be switched back to false from a true state
    target.flag1 = (
      case when source.flag1 >= target.flag1
        then source.flag1 
        else target.flag1 
      end ),
    target.flag2 = (
      case when source.flag2 >= target.flag2
        then source.flag2 
        else target.flag2 
      end ),
    target.flag3 = (
      case when source.flag3 >= target.flag3
        then source.flag3 
        else target.flag3 
      end ),
    target.flag4 = (
      case when source.flag4 >= target.flag4
        then source.flag4 
        else target.flag4 
      end ),
    -- flag 5 can only be true if flag 4 is be false
    target.flag5 = (
      case when target.flag4 = 1 
          or source.flag4 = 1 
        then 0 
        when source.flag5 >= target.flag5
        then source.flag5
        else target.flag5 
      end ),
    -- flag 6 can only be true if flags 4 & 5 are both false
    target.flag6 = (
      case when (target.flag4 = 1 
          or target.flag5 = 1) or 
            (source.flag4 = 1 
          or source.flag5 = 1)
        then 0 
        when source.flag6 >= target.flag6
        then source.flag6
        else target.flag6 
      end ),
    -- flag 7 can only be true if flags 4-6 are all false
    target.flag7 = (
      case when (target.flag4 = 1 
          or target.flag5 = 1
          or target.flag6 = 1) or 
            (source.flag4 = 1 
          or source.flag5 = 1
          or source.flag6 = 1)
        then 0 
        when source.flag7 >= target.flag7
        then source.flag7
        else target.flag7 
      end ),
    -- normal updates
    target.flag8 = source.flag8,
    target.flag9 = source.flag9 
-- no match insert row
when not matched by target then
  insert (
    id,
    flag1,
    flag2,
    flag3,
    flag4,
    flag5,
    flag6,
    flag7,
    flag8,
    flag9
  ) values (
    source.id,
    source.flag1,
    source.flag2,
    source.flag3,
    source.flag4,
    source.flag5,
    source.flag6,
    source.flag7,
    source.flag8,
    source.flag9
 )
;
```